# Does media screen work on TVs and Projectors?

Tags: css

Does `media="screen"` work on TVs and Projectors? like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css">
```

I know we can use `media="screen,projection,tv"` or `media="all"` or remove the media part completely(HTML5), but I really want to know that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically media projection and TV are ignored, and in favor of them we use screen. Newer TVs will render as screen, which makes sense, as they are essentially larger versions of monitors these days.

Projection is used by Opera in fullscreen, but I don't believe that's a considerable factor. These attribute values are from CSS2, I believe standards were a bit open-ended at that point in time. In short: no, you can use screen for everything that isn't print. It will make no difference, but you could still play it safe with a stylesheet for media="screen,projection,tv".

Answer (score 3):

No it would not. `media="screen"` only applies to computer screens

```
Media Type  Description
all         Used for all media type devices
aural       Used for speech and sound synthesizers
braille     Used for braille tactile feedback devices
embossed    Used for paged braille printers
handheld    Used for small or handheld devices
print       Used for printers
projection  Used for projected presentations, like slides
screen      Used for computer screens
tty         Used for media using a fixed-pitch character grid, like teletypes and terminals
tv          Used for television-type devices
```

Comment: I'm going to contend this. It's heavily suggested by some research that Opera is the only browser which supports projectors. I know for a fact that in 2011, a TV at a client's work place would not attribute itself as "tv", preferring the usage of "screen" in Chrome. I don't think Ray's asking what each media means or should be used for, I think he's asking what they -are- used for, and if they're even considerable.

Comment: @VaelVictus Which you are correct, each device is used differently especially when attached to a modern computer or device, but by themselves would use the appropriate media type. A tv that can browse, WebTv or similar, might use screen. If a person is using a tv or projector as their display on a computer, then the media type would be `screen`. But this is for devices that are by themselves. Most of these media types wouldnot be used in the real world anyway.

Comment: More info at https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/media.html . Basically CSS2 does not specify a definitive list of media types that may be values for @media. FWIW just stick to screen and print.